# Why isDisplayed() method is returning false even if the WebElement is present?

Tags: java, selenium

Here's my code:

```
@FindBy(css = "span.et_pb_image_wrap img[title='globeathome ']")
WebElement header1
```

I created a method for this since I am using a POM design pattern:

```
public boolean isImgDisplayed()
 {

    return header1.isDisplayed();

 }
```

here's the HTML tag :

```
<span class="et_pb_image_wrap ">
<img src="https://3p4expkcmfr6hgud4mqt.stratpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/globeathome.png" alt="globeathome stratpoint" title="globeathome" srcset="https://3p4expkcmfr6hgud4mqt.stratpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/globeathome.png 2855w, https://3p4expkcmfr6hgud4mqt.stratpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/globeathome-1280x1037.png 1280w, https://3p4expkcmfr6hgud4mqt.stratpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/globeathome-980x794.png 980w, https://3p4expkcmfr6hgud4mqt.stratpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/globeathome-480x389.png 480w" sizes="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px) 480px, (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 980px) 980px, (min-width: 981px) and (max-width: 1280px) 1280px, (min-width: 1281px) 2855px, 100vw">
</span>
```

My problem is the **isDisplayed()** is returning *false* even if the WebElement is present.

Comment: are you sure that the element is loaded? did you used any wait?

Comment: @GhostCat I have solved my problem, thanks to you. I should've listen to you in the first place. The `config.getStaginURL()` is null, It could be easy if I just focus on the error rather on the code I've added. I sincerely apologize I overacted to your comment, I didn't mean to it is just due to frustrations. I will try to improve myself thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. Rest assured, we have all been in such situations. I am glad we both found back to a reasonable exchange in the end!

Answer (score 2):

check doc -> https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/Difference+between+Selenium+visibility+methods

`isDisplayed()`:
This method determines  if an element is displayed on the screen or not  i.e. whether its width and height are greater than zero, it isn't hidden by CSS, etc. If the element is present on the page, but has style="display:none;" then isDisplayed() will return false.. It returns true if the element is displayed and false if it is not. Advantage of this method is that it avoids parsing an elements style attribute. isDisplayed is used in cases where element is present in DOM and you need to check whether it is displayed or not in the UI. **It is never used to check whether an element is present in the DOM.**

as @Razvan said image may not be loaded

Comment: Then I should get an ElementNotVisibleException right if it doesnt load on the execution time right?

Comment: This will answer to your question :D    https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/isDisplayed%28%29+and+NoSuchElementError+exception